# Postdecrement Operations in While loop

Tags: java

```
b = 5;
    loopiterations = 0;
    while (b-- > 0) {  // Use a postfix decrement
        loopiterations++;         
    }
    System.out.println("Postfix decrement operator used, loopiterations = " +
            loopiterations + ", b = " + b);
```

The result is

> Postfix decrement operator used, loopiterations = 5, b = -1

I don't understand why the value of b is -1. The value of b starts from 5 (after while loop it's value is 4) and then ends at 1 ( after the while loop it is 0) and then the iteration from 5 to 1 is 5.If how I think is right, why is the value of b is -1 after looping. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This block of code

```
   while (b-- > 0) {
      // do something
   }
```

is semantically the same as

```
while (b > 0) {
  b--;
  // do something
}
b--;
```

The loop  `while (b-- > 0)` exits as soon as `b == 0`, but because of the post decrement operation `b` will be one last time decrement and hence `b` will have the value of `-1` when printing.

Comment: You explain with internal working of codes. This is really helpful. Thank you sir.  :)

Answer (score 2):

**postfix increment or decrement actually happens after using value**,
 the initial value of b is 5 so in the first iteration 5 is checked for condition after the last iteration, b becomes 0 after its value (1 at time of comparison) has been decremented, then 0 is checked but the condition is false but due to postfix decrement it's value becomes -1.

**postfix -> first use value then decrement or increment that's how it works**

Comment: _5 is checked for condition < 0_ Maybe a typo?

Answer (score 1):

This is because when `b == 0`, the postfix will return `false` and your while loop will terminate. However, the postifx will still subtract one from `b`. Therefore, the loop is executed 5 times, and `iterations = 5`. However, `b` is decremented 6 times.